# iOS TabBarController / inits ViewControllers by which init-method?

Tags: ios, sdk, uitabbarcontroller

i currently wonder which init-Method is called in the ViewController via TabBarController on tapping a tab.

i tested

> init, initWithStyle, initWithFrame, initWithNibName:andbundle..

but non if them seem to be called.

Any idea, which one is the correct?

for logical reasons i dont want to just use viewDidAppear/Load here..

Any clue?

thanks, Daniel

Comment: hopefully i did not just miss a line in the docs, sorry if i did..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder`
But this happens before the tab is tapped. 
`initWithCoder:` is called when the viewController is added to the UITabBarController.

If you want to respond to a tap on the tab you have to use `viewWillAppear:` `viewDidAppear:` or `viewDidLoad`